# How to make this specific layout 5x1 with space for text on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Im working with bootstrap and i must to this a structure like this, but its not being easy for me. It must has a space for text then 5 columns in one line.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is provided with 12 grid system by default,
For 5 columns you have to make changes to bootstraps ".less" files